# Conversion of alpha from float to int for a Paint object

Tags: android

I want to set the alpha of my paint object to 0.5f or half-transparent. However, the Paint object's setAlpha() method only takes in an int from 0 to 255 (instead of a float). What is the equivalent of an alpha of 0.5f in int? Is it just 127?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be 127. The parameter is explained in the [`getAlpha`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#getAlpha()) method.

> Helper to getColor() that just returns the color's alpha value. This is the same as calling getColor() >>> 24. It always returns a value between 0 (completely transparent) and 255 (completely opaque).